# For what values $p,q$ does the improper integral $\int_0^1 x^p (1-x^2)^q dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

> For what values $p,q$ does the improper integral $\int_0^1 x^p (1-x^2)^q dx$ converge?

I am struggling as I'm not sure where to start. What is the best way to approach this question?

Comment: Let $t=x^2$, and then see [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $x=\sin(t)$. We then get the integral as
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^p(t)\cos^{2q}(t)\cos(t)dt = \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^p(t)\cos^{2q+1}(t)dt=\dfrac12\beta((p+1)/2,q+1)$$
which exists whenever $(p+1)/2>0$ and $q+1>0$, i.e., $p,q>-1$.

Comment: Doesn't $(1-\sin(t)^2)^q = \cos^{2q}(t)$ rather than $(1-\sin(t)^2)^q = \cos^{2q}(t)\cos(t)$? What am I missing?

Comment: @flapjackery You are missing the fact that $dx = \cos(t)dt$.